# How to insert Image into the media directory and inserting post data for that image

Tags: php, wordpress, image

- I want to insert an image from my plugin folder into the media
  library. (make a copy in uploads folder plus have post inserted into database)
- When I go into the admin backend of Wordpress I want to see
  the file in the media tab like any other image.

I don't think I'm copying the file correctly. because if I past the url into my browser it returns blank but if I download the same file my pc is fine with it.

Second problem is I am missing details in the post meta for this image, namely the array for `_wp_attachment_metadata` - I am not sure how to generate this.. or how to create the image sizes that wordpress generates for an image.

*code;*

```
$TheImage='Vodacom.jpg';
$TheDir='images/Vodacom.jpg';
$TheImageName='Vodacom';
$image_url = plugins_url( $TheDir, __FILE__ );
$mySanitizedName = strtolower(str_replace(" ","-",$TheImageName));

$uploaddir = wp_upload_dir();
$uploadfile = $uploaddir['path'] . '/' . $TheImage;

$contents= file_get_contents($image_url);
$savefile = fopen($uploadfile, 'w');
fwrite($savefile, $contents);
fclose($savefile);

$New_image_url = $uploaddir['url']. '/' . $TheImage;

$post_data = array(
        'post_author'   => '1',
        'post_name'     => $mySanitizedName,
        'post_title'    => $TheImageName,
        'post_content'  => '',
        'post_excerpt'  => '',
        'post_status'   => 'publish',
        'ping_status'   => 'closed',
        'post_type'     => 'attachment',
        'post_mime_type'     => 'image/jpeg',
        'guid'          =>  $New_image_url ,
    );

$image_Id = wp_insert_post( $post_data );
update_post_meta( $image_Id, '_wp_attached_file', '2018/12/'.$TheImage );
```

**EDIT:**

I've fix the rest of the inserted post, I can see the thumb nail in the media window, however I still think my file copy is wrong because if I click the thumb , the new window that opens the image file is empty.

So My file copy method is not correct can someone point out why?

new code added to the existing is:

```
require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/image.php');
$attach_data = wp_generate_attachment_metadata( $image_Id, $uploadfile );
$res1= wp_update_attachment_metadata( $image_Id, $attach_data );
```

the thumb showing:
[Thumb](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tx43g.jpg)

the window when opening the thumb:
[window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H7HoV.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I finally figured out my issues.. the issue regarding my file copy not properly working is that on some servers (like mine for example) certain php functionality can be set to false by default , now seeing as my code is for a plugin , I cannot be expected to change server settings so the alternative that worked was to use curl.

Full code below with new curl copy of the file:

```
$TheImage='Vodacom.jpg';
$TheDir='images/Vodacom.jpg';
$TheImageName='Vodacom';
$image_url = plugins_url( $TheDir, __FILE__ );
$mySanitizedName = strtolower(str_replace(" ","-",$TheImageName));

$uploaddir = wp_upload_dir();
$uploadfile = $uploaddir['path'] . '/' . $TheImage;

// Here is the new curl way of copying a file..
$ch = curl_init($image_url);
$fp = fopen($uploadfile, 'wb');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $fp);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
fclose($fp);

$New_image_url = $uploaddir['url']. '/' . $TheImage;

$post_data = array(
    'post_author'   => '1',
    'post_name'     => $mySanitizedName,
    'post_title'    => $TheImageName,
    'post_content'  => '',
    'post_excerpt'  => '',
    'post_status'   => 'publish',
    'ping_status'   => 'closed',
    'post_type'     => 'attachment',
    'post_mime_type'     => 'image/jpeg',
    'guid'          =>  $New_image_url ,
);

$image_Id = wp_insert_post( $post_data );
update_post_meta( $image_Id, '_wp_attached_file', '2018/12/'.$TheImage );
require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/image.php');
$attach_data = wp_generate_attachment_metadata( $image_Id, $uploadfile );
$res1= wp_update_attachment_metadata( $image_Id, $attach_data );
```

I am glad I got this to work, not the ideal way I suppose but it works so...